# RXJS pipe evaluates too often then breaks in Anugular app

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm having issues when I try to fork a Observable (that was piped multiple times): subscribe to it at one place, and pipe and subscribe to it an other place.

I have 2 issues:

- Pipes gets evaluated multiple times. Can I store the pipe results so later observables do not reevaluate?
- The last pipe resets the value of the original observable.

### I have the following setup:

1. I download a list of photos and blog.md files [from the backend](https://github.com/bpatrik/pigallery2/blob/90a5480ff6b08f4d6904e3e2e7dead5bae456d02/src/frontend/app/ui/gallery/contentLoader.service.ts#L41C3-L99) and store it in a BehaviorSubject.

I just simply call the `.next(<new data>)` when the list is downloaded.

3. I [filer this list of photos](https://github.com/bpatrik/pigallery2/blob/90a5480ff6b08f4d6904e3e2e7dead5bae456d02/src/frontend/app/ui/gallery/filter/filter.service.ts#L226-L231) using switchMap and map in a pipe.

relevant part:

```
    return directoryContent.pipe(
        switchMap((dirContent: DirectoryContent) => {
          this.statistic = this.getStatistic(dirContent);
          this.resetFilters(false);
          return this.activeFilters.pipe(
              map((afilters) => {
//logic
})})
```

2. Then, I [sort and group the filtered photos](https://github.com/bpatrik/pigallery2/blob/90a5480ff6b08f4d6904e3e2e7dead5bae456d02/src/frontend/app/ui/gallery/navigator/sorting.service.ts#L210-L219) using switchMap and map rxjs operators:

relevant code part

```
   return directoryContent.pipe(
      switchMap((dirContent) => {
        return this.grouping.pipe(
          switchMap((grouping) => {
            return this.sorting.pipe(
              map((sorting) => {
            // logic
})})})
```

4. Then I [subscribe to this sorted grouped, filtered photos](https://github.com/bpatrik/pigallery2/blob/90a5480ff6b08f4d6904e3e2e7dead5bae456d02/src/frontend/app/ui/gallery/gallery.component.ts#L137-L140) and show the data on the page.

So far it works well, but when I continue it breaks:

5. I also further [pipe the sorted-grouped-filtered photos and md files and I download the actual content of the md files (using promises) from the server](https://github.com/bpatrik/pigallery2/blob/90a5480ff6b08f4d6904e3e2e7dead5bae456d02/src/frontend/app/ui/gallery/blog/blog.service.ts#L18-L30) using mergeMap.

relevant part:

```
   this.groupedMarkdowns = this.galleryService.sortedFilteredContent.pipe(
      mergeMap(async content => {
   /// logic
 })
```

6. Then I just subscribe the Observable in [angular with the async angular pipe in the html](https://github.com/bpatrik/pigallery2/blob/90a5480ff6b08f4d6904e3e2e7dead5bae456d02/src/frontend/app/ui/gallery/blog/blog.gallery.component.html#L1).
   I have multiple instance of the component that subscribes to the same observable.

At this point all my pipes are evaluated multiple time.
Furthermore when I change the filters, all pipes gets evaluated multiple times and with the last evaluation everything resets.

If I do not download the blog files in the last step. All pipes are only evaluated once.

I tried using mergeMap, concatMap and just `map` with a dummy `return []`, but the issue stays.

Comment: Have you looked into shareReplay?

Comment: This is exatly what I was looking for. It solve all my issues. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using [shareReplay](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/sharereplay) solved all my issues. Kudos to maxime1992 for the help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).